# Promise is rejected prematurely multiple times before resolving

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm making a call to an API and then trying to render a chart of the data returned:

```
function getFromAPI(url) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log("Resolving!");
                jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                resolve(jsonData);
            } else {
                console.log("Rejecting!");
                reject();
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    });
}

getFromAPI(API_URL).then( (jsonData) => { drawChart(jsonData) });
```

When I load that script I get `Rejecting!` three times in the console before it resolves. The `reject` is also breaking the `.then` part (i.e. no chart for me!)

I take it the `onreadstatechange` event is firing a few times before we get to `readyState == 4` and `status == 200`. What exactly is going on and how do I avoid rejecting the promise prematurely?

Comment: Because there are readyState's 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) is an event handler that is fired whenever the xhr [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) changes.

```
0   UNSENT  Client has been created. open() not called yet.
1   OPENED  open() has been called.
2   HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
3   LOADING Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
4   DONE    The operation is complete.
```

As you can see there are 4 "not ready" states, and one "done". This accounts for the console log of reject and resolve that you see.

When the request is "done", reject or resolve the request according to the status:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
    return;
  }

  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log("Resolving!");
    jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    resolve(jsonData);
    return;
  }

  console.log("Rejecting!");
  reject();
}
```

Comment: I see, clearly I should therefore not `reject` in the `else` block - but where's the best practice place to `reject` then?

Comment: And if the response code isn't what you are expecting.

Comment: I've fixed and updated the code for checking the status code after the request is done, and rejecting/resolving accordingly.